# Error executing HTTP request: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure.( Managewp to dropbox backup )

Tags: wordpress, ssl, backup, dropbox

I'm troubleshooting a problem on a managedWP backup process on Bluehost for Mysite site which is currently throwing the following error.

This was setup and running at one time and backups to dropbox.

```
Error executing HTTP request: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to SSLv3 no longer being supported by many hosting companies due to an exploit named POODLE. I have come across this error since it first came out and is a serious security risk, that's why it's not longer supported.

Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE#POODLE_attack_against_TLS

You will need to change the TLS/SSL connection to a different version, or more that you will need to tell the plugin creators to do this for you.

I can see on the managedWP website, they do have a support portal so I would recommend you contacted them ASAP.

Comment: Your answer might be correct, but I would not count on it. SSL3_READ_BYTES etc functions in OpenSSL are actually used for TLS1.+ too, same with sslv3 handshake. This means this error message might be misleading and it is not clear what the actual issue is without getting more details (like a packet capture) about the problem.

Comment: Again, this might be the fix but it might also another problem. I've seen lots of other problems which result in the same error message, like no shared ciphers,  no SSL at the peer or simply broken implementations.

Comment: The Dropbox API did disable support for SSLv3 in November, and developers were notified in advance by email. It looks likely that this is the cause of this issue. You should upgrade to using at least TLSv1. If this is a program or plugin from a third party developer, you may need to contact them for an update.

Answer (score 1):

Please update ManageWP worker plugin to the latest version. There was change at DropoBox API, disabling SSLv3 due to security issue. We have received notice from Dropbox, and have updated our library according to that.

Regards,

Miljenko Rebernisak

*Note: I am working at ManageWP*